# if variable is assigned then check some condition in python

Tags: python, if-statement

I am coding in python. My problem is I have a variable `strGUID` in the function and then there is an if control flow in which I want to check if the variable is assigned and if yes then check on some condition on it. Clarifying piece of code is follows :

```
for line in data_list:
    if line.find('Project')!=-1
      strGUID = line.split(',')[2].strip('" ')
    if flag == False and line.find(strGUID)==-1 :
      print 'wrote line : ', line
```

In the above code I get an error sometimes saying

> that the variable strGUID is accesses before its assignment.

so what I want to do is to check in the second if loop if the variable strGUID is defined and if it is then check for condition : `line.find(strGUID)==-1`. Something like

```
if flag == False and (if strGUID then line.find(strGUID)==-1) :
```

PS : this is just to shorten the code and make it intelligent, I know that I can write longer lengthier if checks in the code, so asking for that is not the purpose.

clarification : In case if you want to suggest the answer where you initialli assign strGUID = None and then check it in the second if loop, I want to execute print even when the strGUID is None. Hence I am searching for an intelligent way of defining if condition. i.e. I want print to get executed if strGUID = None or if strGUID is not None and line.find(strGUID)==-1

edit :
basically my current code has second if loop as :

```
if flag == False and (strGUID is None or (strGUID is not None and line.find(strGUID)==-1) ) :
```

I want to check if there is an intelligent way to shorten it.

Comment: Probably because you try to use `strGUID` in the second condition when it's only assigned in the first, but hard to tell because you uploaded partial, badly formatted (== `SyntaxError` in Python) code and "paraphrased" your actual Exception text.

Comment: How could `line.find(strGUID)` possibly be `-1`? You extracted `strGUID` from `line`; it has to be in there somewhere.

Comment: @tejas Please specify more about what you are trying to do and why. Your code is probably not correct so your logic is very difficult to follow, and right now this is very much a game of Pin the Tail on the Donkey.

Comment: @user2357112, Two-Bit Alchemist : Please check the latest edit

Answer (score 2):

The customary way to do this would be to set `strGUID = None` at the start, and then check

```
if flag == False and (strGUID is not None and line.find(strGUID) == -1):
```

If the first part (`strGUID is not None`) is false, the second part (`line.find(strGUID) == -1`) will never be evaluated.

Comment: As long as we're talking customary, `not flag` is preferred to `flag == False`.

Comment: no. This is not correct. I have to print if strGUID = None. So this doesn't work

Comment: @tejas What does "I have to print if strGUID = None" mean?

Comment: @tejas: `strGUID` can't be assigned `None` by the first `if`; that branch will always produce a string. Thus, `None` is a valid sentinel to use here.

Comment: that means your second if looping statement won't go through if strGUID = None. But I do want that to happen